# What is wrong with the if-statements in this source-code?

Tags: python, if-statement

```
fuel = input()
liters = float(input())

if liters >= 25:
    if fuel == "diesel" or "gasolin" or "gas":
        print(f"You have enough {fuel}.")
    else:
        print("Invalid fuel!") # Why that not work

elif liters < 25:
    if fuel == "diesel" or "gasolin" or "gas":
        print(f"Fill your tank with {fuel}!")
    else:
        print("Invalid fuel!") # Why that not work

else:
    print("Invalid fuel!") # Why that not work
```

Comment: python input() always returns a string try converting it to int or float.

Comment: Your comparison line is incorrect.

Try this:

Comment: if fuel == "diesel" or fuel == "gasolin" or fuel == "gas":

Answer (score -1):

`fuel == "diesel" or "gasolin" or "gas"` shuold be changed to `fuel in ("diesel", "gasolin", "gas")` because at the moment the only comparison is fuel and diesel.